# Is Ruby on rails something for me to learn?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

I'm mostly a asp.net developer (and currently work as one), but I'm thinking about expanding my skillset or to learn something else. I'm thinking about learning Ruby on rails. What's the pros and cons with these (preferably from a asp.net (mostly version 2.0) perspective). Anyone
who has any insights?

Comment: I think you should ask more precisely if noone understands what your asking...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easy to learn - and worth a try.

From ASP.NET MVC perspective it's easy to learn. ASP.NET MVC is close to rails - but rails has some more features.

For plain ASP.NET it's a bit harder.

Pro:

- easy to learn
- good to keep on learning new things
- excellent linux/apache integration

Cons:

- learning something new instead of extending existing asp.net knowledge
- Integration in Windows (not good enough from my point of view)

Answer (score 1):

why not? Variety is the spice of life and learning how to perceive code and data in multiple ways should flex your mind to create creative solutions no matter what the problem.  There are things that .NET that are fantastic, while other things that RoR and other frameworks do better.  No way to understand that until you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're learning because you're curious. There's no reason why not. Ruby's a great language and learning any new language is interesting, since it can change the way you think about code.

Yes. if you're learning for job skills. RoR and Ruby skills are in good demand, as it's the highest profile web framework.

Personally, I like Python and Django. You might [check out Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) as the above logic applies to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pro:

Exposure to another stack of tools which could be useful if you want to get into mixed environments.  Seeing a different paradigm in going to a weak typed language.

Con:

There may be many areas closer to ASP.Net that you could choose to take instead including Azure, database development like MS-SQL or Oracle or Javascript frameworks like jQuery or mobile ASP.Net stuff for sites on smartphones or other things that may be closer to what you are doing now.  WCF or WPF may also be options to consider that would be staying within the Microsoft stack in a sense.

While the Pro is certainly a valid one, I would think carefully about what other options are out there that may also be worth doing as well as considering what kind of stuff would you want to do later in your career.